# Heroku CI build artifacts

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci

Does Heroku CI have support for build "artifacts" such as logs, test reports, etc?

At the moment we can only get access to this if we run the debug tests through the Heroku CLI - would love to have access to them through the web interface. We've considered zipping them up and emailing them as a last resort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in the process of migrating from Gitlab and had the same issue. I asked support about this (Feb 2019) and they basically said no - you need to find your own solution.

Their suggestions:

- Run the CI task on a longer-lived dyno and then download the files
- Upload them to S3 in your CI process

In the interim I went with `heroku ci:debug` and then retrieving them via [this method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465789/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-heroku-bash/40721844#40721844)