# Downloading temporary files from heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I have deployed a dyno on heroku and the application is written in python. The application works fine, but my application also writes and reads from excel files. The reading is fine, but the writing is only saved temporarily, which I know is due to heroku's file system. My question is: is there a way to download these excel files from the dyno which are updated with the writing? I have tried to use the heroku git:clone command but that gives me the unchanged spreadsheets. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465789/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-heroku-bash)

Comment: Git isn't for storing data, and modifications don't automatically get committed. You also _shouldn't_ commit anything on Heroku. `heroku run bash` or similar spins up a _new, temporary_ dyno, so you won't see your files there. By far the best solution is not to write data to Heroku's filesystem at all. Save it to S3 or Azure Blob Storage.