# Download code from heroku of a particular branch

Tags: git, github, heroku

I have a client who's code hasn't been released by the developers even after the payment, he still has his Heroku account linked with the GitHub repository that contains the code. I tried to recover it using

`heroku git:clone -a app_name`

however this gets me a much older version of commits that belongs to the `master` branch and the builds are deployed from `/release/1.0` branch. Is there any way I can recover the code without actual access to the Github repo itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this. There's something called [Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) which runs the code in containers, and I can access a `bash` shell. Now what it allows me to do is copy whichever file I want from that Dyno instance.

```
heroku ps:copy tmp/some.log --app app-example-prod --dyno web.1 --output=tmp/some.heroku.log
```

Obviously I needed to download the entire codebase and doing it file by file would have been tedious. Hence I decided to zip all the files, and upload them to a file sharing server using `curl`.

```
zip -r entire-codebase.zip *

curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://file.io/?expires=1h
```

This returned a JSON string that had the URL from where I could download my codebase.

answer by [@Szymon Jez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408011/szymon-je%C5%BC). Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465789/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-heroku-bash) to the official question.