# Successful Deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, deployment, command-line-interface

I Pushed my Files to Heroku CLI using Git Bash By entering This Commands:

> git add -f bot.py Procfile requirements.txt **init**.py
>
> git commit -m "Added Files"
>
> git push heroku master

How Could I Download and Edit the Files that I Pushed to Heroku CLI??
For Example the "conversationboy.py"...
I need To see the file..

Comment: To edit a file, make the changes locally and then repush in the CLI - there's no need to download files

Comment: @Still_learning thank U
Can I See the files that I Pushed?
Can I modify to these Files

Comment: When you originally created the files that you pushed, where did you save them?

Comment: @Still_learning in my computer but my app use text file to read & write from and to them So I need to download and see the Changes of these text files that edited by the app..

Comment: Ah, I understand. Does [this](https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465789/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-heroku-bash/48257411) help?